# The site could not be created The following exception occurred: The language is not supported on the server

Tags: 2010, language

I got a site with english, united states.

**I changed regional settings to ENGLISH, UNITED KINGDOM**

If we installed sharepoint in english, do we also have to install the english language pack?

Then when I create a new site(based on a custom web template), it fails

The log has this error: The site /workspaces/TestingWorkspace2 could not be created. The following exception occurred: The language is not supported on the server..

Actually we create sites via CODE like this:

```
private SPSite CreateNewSiteCollection(string relativeSiteUrl,
                                           string title,
                                           string description,
                                           string webTemplate)
    {
        SPSite newSiteCollection = null;

        // The creation will only work if you set the primary administrator is set to the current user
        //string primarySiteCollectionAdministratorLogin = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
        //string primarySiteCollectionAdministratorName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
        //string primarySiteCollectionAdministratorEmail = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Email;

        string primarySiteCollectionAdministratorLogin = primarySCAdminLogin;
        string primarySiteCollectionAdministratorName = primarySCAdminName;
        string primarySiteCollectionAdministratorEmail = primarySCAdminEmail;

        // Small change you want to set this variable on a different value as the root site collection
        uint localIdentifier = (uint)SPContext.Current.Web.Locale.LCID;

        try
        {
            // Make sure we are at the root site collection
            // using (SPSite rootSite = new SPSite(GetAuthorityUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)))

            SPWebApplication MyWebApplication = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Site.Url));
            string webAppUrl = MyWebApplication.GetResponseUri(SPUrlZone.Default).AbsoluteUri;

            using (SPSite rootSite = new SPSite(webAppUrl))
            {
                // If no secondary site collection administrator is provided, use null values
                // in stead of an empty string. Otherwise an Exception will be thrown.

                newSiteCollection = rootSite.SelfServiceCreateSite(
                                        relativeSiteUrl,
                                        title,
                                        description,
                                        localIdentifier,
                                        webTemplate,
                                        primarySiteCollectionAdministratorLogin,
                                        primarySiteCollectionAdministratorName,
                                        primarySiteCollectionAdministratorEmail,
                                        null,
                                        null,
                                        null);
```

Comment: I also found this link:



http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff463597.aspx


And English United Kingdom - 2057 is not listed there. So it means I can not create sites with locale 2057?

What should I do? Create it with 1033 and then change regional settings programatically?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use

```
uint localIdentifier = (uint)SPContext.Current.Web.Language;
```

to create the new web using the same language as used to create the current web, and then set locale after creation

Comment: SPContext.Current.Web.Language is already uint, no need to cast. I am trying that now :)